# I need an oracle sql extract

Tags: sql, oracle, extract

So I am newer to oracle sql and need a data extract.

I have a table with informations about customers (customers), they can have multiple emails (emailaddresses) which can have multiple usages (usage).

At the moment I have something like this:

```
Select emailaddresses.email as primary, customer.uid as customerUid,
emailaddresses.email as workmail 
Join emailaddresses on emailaddresses.parentid = customer.id
Join usages on usages.parent_id = emailaddresses.id  .... -- here I am stuck
```

workmail:        (where usage.usagetype = 'work';)
and primary:     (where usage.usagetype = 'primary';)

-- now the issue is, i dont know how to select both workmails and primary mails into this extract for one and the same customer. (and customer - uid and id are not the same, I did not invent it and I cannot change it. I just need an extract)

### my tables and columns:

### customer

- uid (int)
- id (varchar)

---

---

### usages

- parent_id (int) -- links to emailaddresses.id
- customer_id (varchar) -- links to customer.id
- usagetype (varchar)

---

---

### emailaddresses

- id (int)
- parentid (varchar) -- links to customer.id
- email (varchar)

---

---

### My expected outcome:

| customeruid | primary | workmail |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01234 | example@mail.com | example@workmail.com |
| 01235 | mail@mail.com | example@work.com |
| 01236 | mail1@mail2.com | mail@work2.com |

Comment: Hi, it would be easier to understand what you're trying to achieve if you showed the columns of your tables and your expected results.

Comment: what is the connection between customers and usages? does usages have a column called usages.customer_id, for example?

Comment: My guess is that you just want `where usage.usagetype in ('work', 'primary')` but your question isn't completely clear.  Posting some sample data and expected results would be very helpful.

Comment: I added the tables and my expected outcome, I hope it is understandable this way. And yes usages and customer are linked

Comment: your edits actually made it less understandable for me, unfortunately, as now I don't get where customer.uid is supposed to fit into the picture i.e. nothing links to customer.uid, so then there should be no difficulty with that column. However, if other people have answered your question correctly, you can just go with those.

Comment: It's hard to write a query without tables and sample data. You can repeat `join usages` (no need for a capital `J`) twice with different aliases to treat it as two tables.

Answer (score 0):

one way you could do is use LISTAGG as follows,

```
select customer_id, listagg(email_id || '   ,   ') within group (order by customer_id) FROM (
select 1 as customer_id, 'hk@gmail.com' as email_id , 'primary' as usagetype from dual UNION
select 1 as customer_id, 'hk@tmail.com' as email_id , 'work' as usagetype from dual UNION
select 2 as customer_id, 'tt@tmail.com' as email_id , 'work' as usagetype from dual 
)group by customer_id
```

Comment: In your solution how do you get rid of the trailing comma as there is no data after it?   CUSTOMER_ID LISTAGG(EMAIL_ID||',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYCUSTOMER_ID)
1 hk@gmail.com   ,   hk@tmail.com   ,   
2 tt@tmail.com   ,

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT CST.UID
             , EA.EMAIL,
             , USG.USAGETYPE
          FROM EMAILADDRESSES EA
             , CUSTOMER       CST
             , USAGES         USG
         WHERE EA.PARENTID = CST.ID
           AND EA.ID       = USG.PARENT_ID 
           AND USG.USAGETYPE IN ('work','primary'))
 PIVOT (MAX(EMAIL) FOR USAGETYPE IN ('work','primary'));
```